# Variable inside function in library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change `the_word` from the function `set_word`. How can I have the old `the_word` replaced so that in the next iteration of the menu the new word is used?

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to the encrypt script")
    the_word = input("Enter the word you want to encrypt\n>>>")
    while True:
        #print("START")
        menu(the_word)

def menu(the_word):
    print("\n\n=============MENU=============")
    actions = {
    '1': ("Encrypt into templar's code", templar),
    '2': ("Encrypt with caesar's code", caesar),
    '3': ("Change the word", set_word),
    '4': ("Exit", stop)
    }

    for i in sorted(actions):
        print('{}. {}'.format(i, actions[i][0]))

    entry = input('Option: ')
    if entry in actions:
        try:
            actions[entry][1]()
        except:
            actions[entry][1](the_word)
    else:
        print("No such command") 

def templar(the_word):
    print("TEMPLAR",the_word) 

def caesar(the_word):
    print("CAESAR",the_word) 

def set_word():
    the_word = input("Enter the word you want to encrypt\n>>>")

def stop():
    print("Thanks for using the encrypt script")
    quit()

main()
```

Comment: You could have `set_word()` return the new word, and assign `the_word` the result of calling `set_word()` in `menu`. Or you could convert `the_word` to be a global, if you were so inclined.

Comment: Or create a class. Would make it more consistent and readable.

Comment: "assign the_word the result of calling set_word() in menu" How would I do this? The function is called inside a library. "Or create a class" I have never used classes before and am not really supposed to either.

Comment: How much of this is your code, and how much was given in the apparent homework assignment?

Comment: This isn't a homework assignment xD I have time left over. The lines that call the library were written by others though, in a different post here on stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable to be shared across your program it should be declared as **global variable**.

In this case, `the_word` variable should be declared as global.

In each function where the global variable value is changed, you should declare it by writing prior to the change : `global the_word`

If you only read the variable you don't have to declare `global the_word`

So your code can be changed to:

```
# declare the_word as global
the_word = ""


def main():
    global the_word
    print("Welcome to the encrypt script")
    the_word = input("Enter the word you want to encrypt\n>>>")
    while True:
        # print("START")
        menu()


def menu():
    global the_word
    print("\n\n=============MENU=============")
    actions = {
        '1': ("Encrypt into templar's code", templar),
        '2': ("Encrypt with caesar's code", caesar),
        '3': ("Change the word", set_word),
        '4': ("Exit", stop)
    }

    for i in sorted(actions):
        print('{}. {}'.format(i, actions[i][0]))

    entry = input('Option: ')
    if entry in actions:
        try:
            actions[entry][1]()
        except:
            actions[entry][1]()
    else:
        print("No such command")


def templar():
    print("TEMPLAR", the_word)


def caesar():
    print("CAESAR", the_word)


def set_word():
    global the_word
    the_word = input("Enter the word you want to encrypt\n>>>")


def stop():
    print("Thanks for using the encrypt script")
    quit()


main()
```

Comment: I've used globals before, but everyone told me not to. I know that you should avoid them, especially in larger programs so I'm trying to back away from them.